# Mac mail plugin: how to delete a message?

Tags: objective-c, macos, email, plugins

i'm developing a plugin for Apple Mac Mail and i can't find a way to delete a message (email).
I have a object (Message class) representing email, but there is no obvious way to delete a corresponding message. Can't find anything related in google too.

Comment: Have you looked at using the applescript interface?

Comment: Well, no. Could it be accessed from objective-c?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about doing it directly from your plugin, but it can certainly be done using the applescript interface. And, the applescript interface can be used from Obj-C using the [scripting bridge](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptingBridgeConcepts/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: Yeah, thank you. I just tried and it did work. I'll wait for a couple of hours and if no solution without applescript would be posted, i'll accept you answer.